# BASH check directory and continue or wait

Tags: bash

I have a script that groups together files found in a directory and e-mails them.

There is a problem though as sometimes the script is triggered by the CRON so it starts but there are still files being added to the directory.

At the start of the script I need to implement a check that gets the number of files in the directory remembers it and then does the check again in for e.g. 30 seconds.

If the numbers are the same then it should continue, or if the last check is greater than the first then the script should completely exit.

What is the best way to do such a check?

Answer (score 1):

you mean like so?

```
NFILES1=`find . -type f | wc -l`
sleep 30
NFILES2=`find . -type f | wc -l`
if [ $NFILES1 -ne $NFILES2 ]; then
    echo "The file-creator is still going, apparently; exiting."
    exit
fi
# carry on
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop to check the number of files every 30 seconds. e.g.:

```
a=-1
b=-2
while ((a!=b))
do 
    b=a
    a=$(find yourfolder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "a" | wc -c)
    sleep 30
done
```

Comment: yeah, that'd match the title of the question. the body, however, says "if the last check is greater than the first then the script should completely exit". so one or the other! :)

Comment: +1 for the printf to avoid being confused by files with linebreaks in the names!

Comment: So would this not do what is required in the description? Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to have the process placing files create a single specifically-named  file (e.g. `all.done`) at the end of it's run, and the process that consumes the files check for that specific file before doing anything else, and exiting if it's not there...